# Google Analytics shows iPhone in Android app

Tags: android, google-analytics

i working on android application project that use Google Analytics. Application is still in aplha testing stage. After a few days of tests i noticed that in analytis dashboard is listed an iPhone device but there is no iPhone version of my application. Is it a problem with GA or some problems in my configuration? It's really strange and i'm worried if my application safety.

I will be grateful for any suggestions or informations.

Comment: How are you using Google Analytics? Are you using Analytics provided Google Play services?

Comment: @djabi Yes, i use lastest (ver. 7) of Google Play Services.

Comment: You can't configure Android Analytics to appear as iPhone by accident. Its probably spam. Can you see the countries where the iPhone devices appear to be? Be careful to not open any referrer URL that comes with the fake hits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is so-called referral spam. More information in the bellow links:

http://moz.com/blog/how-to-stop-spam-bots-from-ruining-your-analytics-referral-data
https://megalytic.com/blog/how-to-filter-out-fake-referrals-and-other-google-analytics-spam
http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/

**Updated**

I've handled this issue like this:

1. Go to your app view in the Google Analytics.
2. Open the 'Admin' tab.
3. Click on 'View settings'.
4. There will be section called 'Bot Filtering', check the 'Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders' option.

From now on Google will remove the spam hits from their analytics. This solution has two issues, though:

1. Historical data will not be affected by this option, i.e. spam hits
   which were made in the past will remain in your data, Google will
   only filter your future hits.
2. Google promises to remove hits from known bots, which means that the
   time from the new bot appearance to the moment when it will be
   included in the Google filter list can be indefinitely long. I use
   this solution for the last week though and didn't find any new bots
   breaking through the filter.